# Does `npm search` not work when github packages is configured in .npmrc

Tags: npm, github-package-registry

I'm experimenting with configuring things to use [Github Packages](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages) for private components.  That's working fine.  But in directories where I have things configured to search `github` before `npmjs`, `npm search` seems to have stopped working.  I tried searching for one of my packages or just something like `lodash` and I get this error:

```
npm search @hapi/joi
npm WARN search fast search endpoint errored. Using old search. 
npm WARN Failed to read search cache. Rebuilding
npm WARN Building the local index for the first time, please be patient
npm WARN Search data request failed, search might be stale
npm ERR! No search sources available
```

This still works fine in dirs without the `.npmrc` pointing to github packages

The .npmrc are pretty basic,

```
registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/mycompany
```

Is this just working as designed, or is there configuration that will allow me to search (IDEALLY) my private repo AND the `npmjs` repo?  My user `~/.npmrc` looks like:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
//npmjs.org
```